# Removing words starting with 'http' in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I previously asked this but I got the data type wrong!

I have my Pandas Dataframe, which looks like this

```
print(data)
      text
0      FollowFriday    for being top engaged members...
1      Hey James! How odd :/ Please call our Contact...
2      we had a listen last night :) As You Bleed is...
```

In this dataframe theree are links, which all start with "http". I have already got a line of code in a function, below, which removes words starting with '@' and other cleaning methods.

```
def cleanData(data):
    #Loop through the data, creating a new dataframe with only ascii characters
    data['text'] = data['text'].apply(lambda s: "".join(char for char in s if char.isascii()))
    #Remove any tokens with numbers, or digits.
    data['text'] = data['text'].apply(lambda s: "".join(char for char in s if not char.isdigit()))
    #Removes any words which start with @, which are replies. 
    data['text']= data['text'].str.replace('(@\w+.*?)',"")
    #Remove any left over characters 
    data = data['text'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
    #return the cleaned data
    return data
```

Can anyone help to remove words which start with 'http' please? I have already tried to edit what I have but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return data[~data['text'].str.startswith('http')]` ?

Comment: I think OP meant word rather than the whole row @anky

Comment: @Vishnudev ahh I see. The example is a bit convoluted for me. :)

Comment: Yeah. For me too. @anky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.str.replace`

```
data['text'] = data['text'].str.replace('http[^\s]*',"")
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this actually worked. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the str.replace() method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( dict(text = [r'FollowFridayhttphttp  http http for being top engaged members.',r'James!http How odd http:/ Please call ou',r'httpe had a listen last night :) As You Bleed is...']))

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('http',''))
```

And you could do something like this in your function.

Comment: Or if you meant the entire word associated with http, that would be a different story. Let me know. For example, the above code reduces 'http://foo bar' to '://foo bar' not ' bar'